# Why I can't connect to mysql docker locally with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, docker

I follow the official documentation for Windows at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x#getting-started-on-windows.

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash

cd example-app
 
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

Containers are fine and running. I open mysql command line and run:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

I enter no password (just enter) and I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: By default, sail will not allow database access without a password. The password is what is provided in your docker-compose.yml under `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` where the default value of this is `DB_PASSWORD` (which I think comes from your .env file)

Comment: if mysql runs in a container and your client runs on host, then you should see those as 2 different machines. Meaning `root` is not on `localhost`. Try to allow `root` access from `%`